# Seg Fault - Passing variable to method changes global value

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm a newbie to c++ and am trying to do some basic object creation using dynamic memory.
I'm passing an int argument to a method and it is changing the value of the global variable. I think it has something to do with the way I'm allocating memory for new objects, I cant get it to compile any other way.

```
int main () {
    int inp;
    CRectangle rectb (2,2);
    cout << "enter number of items to add" << endl;
    cin >> inp; // let's say inp = 7
    rectb.addItemsArray(inp);
    cout << "inp after adding items: " << inp << endl; // inp is now 1.
}
```

header files:

```
class CRectangle {
    int width;
    int height;
    item *items[]; // SOLUTION: change this line to "item *items"
    int input;

public:
        CRectangle (int,int);
        int addItemsArray(int);
        int area () { return (width*height); }
        int get_items(int);

};
```

-and-

```
class item {
    int foo;
    char bar;
public:
    //SOLUTION add "item ();" here (a default constructor declaration without arguments)
    item (int, char);
    int get_foo();
    char get_bar();
};
```

method:

```
int CRectangle::addItemsArray(int in) {
    cout << "value of in at begginning:" << in << endl; //in = 7
    int i;
    i = 0;
    //SOLUTION: add "items = new item[in];" on this line.
    while (i < in) {
        items[i] = new item(1, 'z'); //SOLUTION: change this line to "items[i] = item(1, 'z');"
        i++;
    }
    cout << "value of in at end " << in << endl; //in = 7
    return 1;
}
```

Sometimes I get a bus error or seg fault. Sometimes it works as expected with lower numbers like 2 or 3, but not always.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit (CRectangle's constructor):

```
CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
}
```

(item's constructor):

```
/* SOLUTION add default item constuctor
item::item() {
    foo = 0;
    bar = 'a';
}
*/

item::item(int arg, char arg2) {
    foo = arg;
    bar = arg2;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Crectangle constructor's implementation?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see how it initializes `items`. (And why aren't you using something like a `vector` that does all this stuff for you?)

Comment: Without the rest of the code for the class, it's hard to know what's wrong.  However, my first guess would be related to your item array.  Do you ever (re)allocate space to record the pointers to new items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to create the items array...

You defined a dynamic allocated array (not item *items[100], but item *items[]). Before you can use the array, you have to allocate memory to hold the items:

```
items = new item[100];
```

and dont forget to delete it with

```
delete [] items;
```

at the end. ;)

And instead of

```
int i;
i = 0;
while (i < in) {
   items[i] = new item(1, 'z');
   i++;
}
```

i would use

```
for (int i=0; i<in; i++)
{
   items[i] = new item(1, 'z');
}
```

Comment: I added "items = new item[100];" to the CRectangle constructor but it wont compile that way. Adding "item *items[100]" to the items declaration works, I'm trying to allocate memory at runtime. Do I always have to allocate an over-estimation (100) for the array?

Comment: /*** I've edited my solution into the OP. ***/ It's basically a modified version of your solution, DirkMausF. Tx.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you haven't allocated any storage for the pointers you put into `items`. I would suggest changing:

```
item *items[];
```

to

```
std::vector<item*> items;
```

and then add items to it with:

```
items.push_back(new item(1, 'z'));
```

Comment: Or, for added simplicity, `std::vector<item> items` and `items.push_back(item(1, 'z'));`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've avoided using vector, because I'm trying to learn how to do things more natively (without using other classes) before I start using helpful tools like string and vector.